# base_library.zip could not be extracted! fopen permission denied

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I have created a simple python application (using tkinter module) on my personal windows PC and converted it into an executable file using pyinstaller.
However, I am not able to run the same program on my office PC having restricted access.
The error that I get on the PC is **'base_library.zip could not be extracted! fopen permission denied'**

Comment: So what do you think the reason for this error 'base_library.zip could not be extracted! fopen permission denied' is? The only reason I wrote admin access is because the error says permission denied in extracting, which make sense because the PC that I use has restricted access.

Comment: @super_shrey PyInstaller would extract files inside temp directory. Have you tried creating a file in that directory manually?

Comment: @M.R.I tried doing it. But everytime the executable is run, it creates a new folder in the temp location. (C:\Users\Shreyan\AppData\Local\Temp\\_MEI133522)

Answer (score 1):

I was able to run it successfully by manually extracting the contents of base_library.zip in the path of the .exe file.